# Why are some of the iterations of for loop skipped in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

The execution of body of the for loop is skipped at multiple times.

I tried running this code and got unexpected results. I noticed while debugging that some times the body of the for loop is just not executed. I checked for wrong indentation, but it seems fine.

```
    def getOutput (X):
        # Write your code here
        sum = 0
        if int(X) not in setA:
            setA.append(int(X))
            setA.sort()

        for a in range(len(setA)-1):

            if a == 0:
                low = 1
            else:
                low = setA[a-1] + 1
            sum += low

            if  a == (len(setA)-1):
                high = N
            else:
                high = setA[a+1] - 1
            sum += high
            #print(setA, a, low, high)

        return sum

N, M = map(int, input().split())
setA = []
while M > 0:
    X = input()
    out_ = getOutput(X)
    print (out_)
    M -= 1

Sample Input:
10 10
2 
7
5
9
6
1
8
10
3
4


Expected output for the above input:
11
20
30
46
58
61
77
96
102
110
```

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to do?

Comment: I am trying to solve the good ranges problem
https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/the-good-ranges-1456e1a2-e908a292/

Comment: And what are you using as inputs? Splitting on input() then mapping it to ints seems very odd.

Comment: I give N and M values a 10 10 on the first line, and then more numbers- 2, 7,.. on one line each, as provided in the sample input of the problem.

Comment: if it's skipping for loop then it's possible that len(setA) is <=1

Comment: The  minimum value of len(setA) is 1 in the fist iteration of the while loop. But the body of the for loop is expected to be run even for a single element in the list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop should be `for a in range(len(setA)):`

instead of `for a in range(len(setA)-1):`

I have tried to iterate the loop for all indices in the list.
range(len(setA) - 1) excludes the iteration for the last element of the list.
This is because the range function by default excludes the last element.

eg: range(5) would give us [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

So no need to add the -1 in the above code.